# Function returning type unit instead of type ref

Tags: f#, return-type, ref, imperative

Here I am attempting to use an imperative style factorial function, but despite the last line of the function declaring a `ref` to be returned, fsc is telling me that the function is returning a unit. I know mutables are not allowed to be returned, but I thought you could circumvent that by using a `ref`? Also, please do not tell me to rewrite it in a functional way. I know that is an alternative, but I am trying to get a better understanding of how imperative programming works in the language.

Here is my program:

```
let factorial n = do
    let res = ref 1
    for i = 2 to n do
        res := !res * i
    res 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main(args : string[]) = 
    let result = factorial 10
    printfn "%d" !result
```

This is what the compiler gives me:

```
factorial.fs(2,5): warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit',     but
has type 'int ref'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, 
or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

factorial.fs(10,13): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> int
but given a
    'a -> unit
The type 'int' does not match the type 'unit'

factorial.fs(10,19): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a ref
but here has type
    unit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is remove `do`, `do` used in this context is specifically for performing side-effects, hence the expected return type of unit.

Also, your function is not correct, you need to replace `n` with `i` in the loop.

```
let factorial n =
    let res = ref 1
    for i = 2 to n do
        res := !res * i
    res
```

By the way, you don't need to use references, you can just write it like this:

```
let factorial n =
    let mutable res = 1
    for i = 2 to n do
        res <- res * i
    res
```

Comment: Thank you pointing out the error in my function. However, removing the first do only gets rid of the second error, and removing the one after the for loop gives an error that I have an incomplete structured construct.The alternative function you provided also gives me the first error.

Comment: @GuitarGuy365 You need to the `do` after `for`.  I will look at your other error but I tested this code and it worked.

Comment: @GuitarGuy365 I think you don't have a `0` at the end of your program.  Add a `0` on a new line after `printfn...`.  `main` should return `int`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!